# Menu responsive (menutron.js) + tab jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, tabs, responsive-design

I have the following tab menu based on a simple jquery script, but I would like to implement the responsive version with plugin menutron.js

Any idea how could I run the select in the responsive version?

```
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });

    $("#sidebar").menutron({
        maxScreenWidth: 400,
        menuTitle: 'Menu Responsive'
    });
```

Version normal:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GdQbaHL.png]

Version responsive:

[image]

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/y0vLoasm/3/

Comment: a quick glance over the plugin source shows that it only works with full urls. Which means you cannot use it for what you want

Comment: Any possible solution?

Comment: posted an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to your issue. I manually create the `select` element, and delegate changes to it to the actual links. So whatever code you have there will execute when using the `select` navigation.

I create the `select` element at start and use a media query to show/hide it based on browser width

**CSS**

```
#sidebar > .tabs-menu{display:block}
#sidebar > select{display:none;}

@media (max-width:400px){
    #sidebar > .tabs-menu{display:none}
    #sidebar > select{display:block}
}
```

**javascript**

```
var select = $('<select><option>Menu Cierra Puertas</option></select>'),
    tabLinks = $(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this),
        parent = self.parent(),
        tab = self.attr('href'),
        index = tabLinks.index(this);

    parent.addClass("current")
          .siblings().removeClass("current");

    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();

     // highlight the option in the select so it matches current one
     select[0].options[index+1].selected = true;
});

// create the select options
tabLinks.each(function(idx, item){
    $('<option>',{
        text: $(this).text()
    }).appendTo(select);
});
// handle navigation from the select element
select.appendTo('#sidebar')
      .on('change', function(){
          var index = this.selectedIndex-1;
          if (index >= 0 ){
              tabLinks.eq(index).trigger('click');
          }
      });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/v95r32ym/